# cannot access '<init>': it is public /*package*/ in 'Constructor'

Tags: kotlin, reflection, yaml

I am trying to parse a yaml in Kotlin using SnakeYAML following [this tutorial](https://www.mkammerer.de/blog/snakeyaml-and-kotlin/):

```
data class Case(val args: List<String>, val expected: String, val score: Int)
data class TestCases(val target: String, val cases: List<Case>)

val yaml = Yaml(Constructor(TestCases::class.java))
```

but the code returns these errors in IntelliJ

> Cannot access '<init>': it is public/*package*/ in 'Constructor'

for using `Constructor` as in `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`, and

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
>
> - public constructor Yaml(dumperOptions: DumperOptions!) defined in org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
> - public constructor Yaml(loadingConfig: LoaderOptions!) defined in org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
> - public constructor Yaml(constructor: BaseConstructor!) defined in org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
> - public constructor Yaml(representer: Representer!) defined in org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

for using `Yaml` as in `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml`, which I think is expecting a `BaseConstructor` from `Constructor`.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are importing wrong class. It should be `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor` instead of `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`.