# How to fix this Error with Timestamp(Date()) in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use this code that I found on the firebase website
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#data_types)

Not only that, but other people are using Date() as part of their code and it gives me errors for some reason. Here is the error I am getting on my code.

[image]

Here are the imports I have for this :

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.google.type.Date
```

Any solutions to this would be greatly appreciated. I believe the error is aligned with the imports with Date.

Comment: Ok: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53413776/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65268300/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51054789/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59498497/5468463, etc...

Comment: @Vega similar errors, however does not necessarily address the issue that I am having with Timestamp and Date() inside of it. From what I found, it seems to be a package, don't know exactly what is wrong with the package since I am a bit new to kotlin therefore none of those posts exactly address my question. Two of them I came across before already.

Comment: For that, you need to post [mre] first. The code image is useless and is not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the wrong Date class.  Your screenshot shows that you are using `com.google.type.Date`, but Firestore's [Timestamp constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#Timestamp(java.util.Date)) only allows a `java.util.Date` type argument.  Correct your imports and try again.

Comment: I am using kotlin, that java.util.Date does not work in my imports. Is it only useful for Java then?

Comment: It does not matter if you're using Kotlin or Java.  java.util.Date is an object provided by the JDK that is perfectly usable by both languages.  The entire Java API provided by the underlying JDK is usable by Kotlin, as they run in the same environment.  Without seeing your entire code and any additional error message, it's not possible to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I was getting an error because I had another import of Date implemented! I fixed it up. It works all smoothly now. Thanks a lot for you help!